# Issue with extjs direct store and extdirectspring

Tags: spring-mvc, extjs, extjs4, ext-direct

Using extdirectspring with extjs 4.1,
I'm trying to do some callback action with my direct store action response (destroy in my case), but can't find a way to send any info as part of response from my store_modify method.
I can do this in form_post but not in store_modify.

More specifically, how could I send a custom message as part of response?

The way i do it in form_post

```
@ExtDirectMethod(FORM_POST)
@RequestMapping(value = "/userUpdate", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void userUpdate(Locale locale,
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        @Valid User user, BindingResult result) {
    ExtDirectResponseBuilder extResponse = ExtDirectResponseBuilder.create(
            request, response);
            extResponse.addResultProperty("message", "some custom msg");

}
```

My Model

```
Ext.define('PCE.model.User', {
extend : 'Ext.data.Model',
requires : [ 'Ext.data.UuidGenerator' ],
idgen : 'uuid',
.
.
.
proxy : {
    type : 'direct',
    api : {
        //create :
        //update : 
        destroy : userService.destroy
    },
    reader : {
        root : 'records'
    }
 }
});
```

My spring controller method

```
@ExtDirectMethod(STORE_MODIFY)
public void destroy(User user) {
    userRepository.delete(user);

/* how to add some mesage here as in form post above? /*


}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how you implemented direct store? can you include some code ?

Comment: thanks jomet, here comes the code sample ;)